# Laravel 5.5 Route Controller [ Page not found ]

Tags: php, laravel

I have a program that uses `$router->resource([])`. I use laravel-admin.

here my routes.php

```
$router->resources([
    'programs'             => ProgramController::class,
    'programs/categories'  => ProgramCategoryController::class,
]);
```

on my `programs` its work well with all the `crud` operation.

but on my `programs/categories` its not working, said not found. did `route controller` must use different `url`?...

i mean my category can't be `child` from my programs with different controller?...

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307335/5013099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Supplementing Resource Controllers

If you need to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default set of resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to `Route::resource;` otherwise, the routes defined by the `resource` method may unintentionally take precedence over your supplemental routes:

```
Route::get('photos/popular', 'PhotoController@method');

Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

So on my case above, just simply change this:

```
$router->resources([
    'programs'             => ProgramController::class,
    'programs/categories'  => ProgramCategoryController::class,
]);
```

to this :

```
$router->resources([
    'programs/categories'  => ProgramCategoryController::class,
    'programs'             => ProgramController::class,
]);
```

and it's working well now, also both `crud` operations.

it's not an optimal solution but its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "programs/categories" to "programs.categories"

Comment: same, page not found.

Comment: What is the url, and what does your controller action method look like?

Comment: `admin/programs` and `admin/programs/category` for specific category model that have a relationship to the program, but its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add "programs" prefix to categories resource routes. You can do it by changing you code as follows:

```
$router->resources([
    'programs'             => ProgramController::class,
]);



// to add programs prefix to categories routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'programs'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->resource('categories', ProgramCategoryController::class);

    // here you can add more routes and all those routes will have 
    // "programs" prefix in there url
});
```